# Meaning of exclamation mark in zipAll(s).takeWhile(!_._2.isEmpty)

Tags: scala, syntax

What is the explanation mark doing in `(!_._2.isEmpty)` ?

As in :

```
  def startsWith[A](s: Stream[A]): Boolean = 
    zipAll(s).takeWhile(!_._2.isEmpty) forAll {
      case (h,h2) => h == h2
    }
```

taken from [Stream](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/laziness/Stream.scala).

Is it just negation ?

If yes, why no space is required between `!` and `_` ?

Is not `!_` interpreted as a method name ?

Can method names contain or start with `!` ?

Comment: `!_` is the same as `!x`, except for what `_` means. That is, both `x` and `_` are a valid (complete-in-context) identifier and Scala (for better or worse) is not white-space sensitive here. In the entire context it is equivalent to the form with explicit parenthesis - `!(((_)._2).isEmpty)`. Overkill, but it ought to show the parsing breakdown.

Comment: (The white-space/identifier lex'ing rules also explain why `foo_=` must be used and not `foo=`, the latter of which is parsed as `foo`, `=`. And *all* of this is covered in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/).)

Answer (score 1):

It is just negation.  expanding the definition by replacing the _ with a more verbose name might make this more obvious.

```
def startsWith[A](s: Stream[A]): Boolean = 
zipAll(s).takeWhile(!_._2.isEmpty) forAll {
  case (h,h2) => h == h2
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
def startsWith[A](s: Stream[A]): Boolean = 
zipAll(s).takeWhile( element => !element._2.isEmpty) forAll {
  case (h,h2) => h == h2
}
```

._2 is just the second item in a tuple, in this case it looks like this list is a pair of items (references later as h and h2) so you could also rewrite this by unpacking the items into a pair of values as

```
def startsWith[A](s: Stream[A]): Boolean = 
zipAll(s).takeWhile{ element =>
  val (h, h2) = element
  !h2.isEmpty
} forAll {
  case (h,h2) => h == h2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just negation?

Yes

> If yes, why no space is required between ! and _ ?

Because the grammar allows it

> Is not !_ interpreted as a method name ?

No, because `.` associates stronger than `!`, so the expression is parsed as `!(_._2.isEmpty)`

Moreover, `!_` is not even a valid method name (again, specified in the grammar, see below)

> Can method names contain or start with `!`?

Yes, but not freely.  Here's the rules for identifier naming, straight from the language specification:

> There are three ways to form an identifier. First, an identifier can start with a letter
>   which can be followed by an arbitrary sequence of letters and digits. This may be
>   followed by underscore ‘
>   _
>   ’ characters and another string composed of either letters
>   and digits or of operator characters. Second, an identifier can start with an operator
>   character followed by an arbitrary sequence of operator characters. The preceding
>   two forms are called
>   plain
>   identifiers. Finally, an identifier may also be formed by an
>   arbitrary string between back-quotes (host systems may impose some restrictions
>   on which strings are legal for identifiers). The identifier then is composed of all
>   characters excluding the backquotes themselves.
>   As usual, a longest match rule applies.

([The Scala Language Specification, Version 2.9, Chapter 1.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf))